# How to get variable out of aysnc function

Tags: intern

How do I get a variable out of an async function?

I have the following and I'd like to get the httpsResp variable from this async function.

```
        var httpsResp;
        var dfd = this.async(10000);

        var httpsReq = https.request(httpOptions, dfd.callback(function (resp) {
           httpsResp = resp.statusCode;
           assert.strictEqual(httpsResp, correctResp, error.incorrectResp);
        }), dfd.reject.bind(dfd));
        httpsReq.end();
        httpsReq.on('error', function(e) {
          console.error(e);
        });
        console.info('Status Code: ' + httpsResp);
```

Currently, httpsResp shows undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar points out, the basic question is already answered in [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). Since `https.request` is an asynchronous, the call to `https.request` simply initiates a network request and returns immediately (i.e., before the request is completed), then the remaining statements in your function, including the call to `console.info`, are evaluated. Asynchronous operations in JavaScript cannot interrupt an executing function, so your request callback won't be called until sometime after the outer function returns.

A common way to handle this situation is to put any code that cares about the value of `httpsResp` in the asynchronous callback. For a test this generally means assertions, which your code is already doing.